# Why are some config options not appearing in my jenkins UI?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-plugins

I recently started learning devops and am currently stuck. The videos that I am watching have a lot of options in pipeline's config that do not appear in my UI.

[image: My UI]

[image: The video's UI]

I have admin rights by the way. But for example, when adding the plugin "ignore commit strategy", there is no place where I can configure it in my pipeline, nothing is appearing. The solution may be dumb, but I am new and sadly really stuck.

[image: My UI with no ignore commit strategy config available]

[image: Video's UI with the option]

I tried to recreate a new docker container, an older version of jenkins, bypassing the security to see if it was because of some rights, I searched everywhere to check if the config was not just in another place. If anyone could help it would be great ! Thank you !